# Pundit: auhorize Index in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested, authorization, pundit

Using Rails 4.2.4 with Devise (3.5.2) and Pundit (1.0.1). Decent_exposure (2.3.2).

I have a simple nested associaton for User and Idea:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ideas
...

class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
...
```

In routes.rb

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :ideas
end
```

Then I am simply trying to disallow access to users/1/ideas if current_user is not the owner of the Ideas (in this example, if current_user.id != 1).
I can not figure out how to do it. I am able to show just the current_user Ideas in the Index view with:

[Ideas controller]

```
def show
  authorize idea
end
```

[Idea policy]

```
def show?
  @current_user == @idea.user
end
```

But how can I prevent a user to simply navigate to other user's Idea index page?
I guess that in Ideas controller I should use something like:

```
def index
  authorize user
end
```

But then what? How can I send to the User Policy the info regarding the Idea collection?
Or should I authorize via the Idea Policy itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Duplicating [my response on GitHub](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/324#issuecomment-150600211) here because this gets more traffic.

---

One way is to create a stub `Idea` owned by the user to authorize against.

```
def index
  @user = User::find(params[:user_id])
  idea  = Idea.new(user_id: @user.id)

  authorize idea

  # ...
end
```

and an `index?` method in your `IdeaPolicy`

```
def index?
  record.user_id = user.id
end
```

Another way is to change what you're authorizing against. Instead of authorizing against `Idea`, authorize against the `User`.

```
def index
  @user = User::find(params[:user_id])

  authorize @user, :show_ideas?

  # ...
end
```

and create a new `show_ideas?` method on your `UserPolicy`

```
def show_ideas?
  user.id == record.id
end
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! Many thanks. The second approach is more intuitive for me. Thanks again!

Comment: The second approach definitely makes more sense and is easier to understand. :)

Comment: deefour, which one is the preferred way? (I'm using devise for authentication)

Comment: @SzilardMagyar the first way sits better with me. The second approach, though arguably more readable at first glance, pollutes the `UserPolicy` in my opinion. I prefer to keep policy actions as crud-like as possible: `index? new? create? edit? update? destroy?`. When I start thinking of creating actions like `can_apply_batch_action?` it usually means I'm trying to authorize against the wrong model.

Comment: @deefour Does this mean it is "okey" if I have nested routes (e.g. all models nested in `Team` model) and just do `authorize @team, :some_policy?` in every other model's controllers/views? And all the policies are stored in `team_policy.rb`? Thanks for the help!