# Admin privileges in Pundit with nested resources and how to handle the index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, authorization, pundit

I'm new to pundit and trying to come up with the best approach for handling nested resources for the index action. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303718/pundit-auhorize-index-in-nested-resources) however it doesn't deal with admin privileges and I'm just not sure if my solution feels quite right.

Let's say I have two models, a `User` can have many notes and a `Note` which belongs to a single user. Users *cannot* look at notes from other users unless they're an admin.  At the same time, admin's are able to create their own notes and therefore must also have the ability to retrieve a list of them via their own index action.

***routes.rb***

```
resources :users, only: :show do
  resources :notes
end
```

***notes_controller.rb***

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

  #would probably move to application_controller.rb
  after_action :verify_authorized
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped

  def index
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @notes = policy_scope(user.notes)
    authorize user
  end

  #additional code
end
```

***note_policy.rb***

```
class NotePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin? && scope != user.notes
        scope
      else
        user.notes
      end
    end
  end

  #additional code
end
```

***user_policy.rb***

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def index?
    user == record || user.admin?
  end

  #additional code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it:

```
class NotePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.where(user: user)
    end
  end

  def index?
    record == user || user.admin?
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note here that its a good idea to chain from the scope being passed in from `policy_scope`. It lets your controller set up any scopes unrelated to authorization like for example pagination.

Also in `index?` we are cheating slightly. Instead of passing a note instance we are just passing the user.

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user!, only: [:index] # ...
  before_action :set_note!, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @notes = policy_scope(Note.all)
    authorize(@user)
  end

  # ...

  private
    def set_user!
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end 

    def set_note!
      @note = authorize( Note.find(params[:id]) )
    end
end
```

Using `before_action` in this way is a pretty good pattern as it sets up all the "member" actions for authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply max and I appreciate the example. The main issue I'm struggling with is how to give an admin the ability to view notes from other users (in addition to their own) when visiting different index pages. I'd rather not pollute the controller with that logic if possible, however there seems to be no simple way of passing pundit an additional params variable to check against. I get it, it's by design but there's probably a cleaner way of achieving it than what I've come up with so far.  I'm probably just missing something.